# Compiling Ayende's Binsor with trunk Boo

Tags: c#, boo, binsor

I'm trying to update our references, including Boo. When compiling Binsor, I'm getting a bunch of errors, which I'm hacking away one at a time. After much source browsing and googling, I'm unable to figure out how to fix the following line ([TransformUnknownReferences.cs](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/commons/Rhino.Commons.Binsor/TransformUnknownReferences.cs), line 115):

```
ExternalConstructor constructor = new ExternalConstructor(TypeSystemServices, constructorInfo);
```

The [ExternalConstructor](http://svn.codehaus.org/boo/boo/trunk/src/Boo.Lang.Compiler/TypeSystem/Reflection/ExternalConstructor.cs) constructor, as of revision 3260, is:

```
public ExternalConstructor(IReflectionTypeSystemProvider provider, ConstructorInfo ci)
```

I have not figured out where TypeSystemServices comes from, or how I get to an IReflectionTypeSystemProvider from this point in the Binsor code. If anyone with deep Binsor and/or Boo knowledge knows of an easy fix, please speak up :).

Better yet would be some sort of hidden Binsor repository, where the code has been updated during the last six months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is very old. The current repository of [Rhino.Commons is on github](http://github.com/lorenzomelato/rhino-commons).

Comment: Thank you for the easiest possible route to success :).